# Sort value in dictionary that resides within an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I have an `Array`: `var messageArray = [AnyObject]()` and in that `Array` there is a single tuple that contains `Dictionaries` with 10 key/value paires (9 of them not important for the sort): `var messageDetailDict = [String: AnyObject]()`

Getting and setting those values all work correctly, however now I want to **sort the `Array` by 1 of the values (not keys) of the `Dictionary`**.

**Example -> The `Array` has a tuple containing several `Dictionaries`:**

The key in the `Dictionary` (which is the first element in the `Array`) is: 'ReceivedAt' which has a value of 21-03-2015

The key in the `Dictionary` (which is the second element in the `Array`) is: 'ReceivedAt' which has a value of 20-03-2015

The key in the `Dictionary` (which is the third element in the `Array`) is: 'ReceivedAt' which has a value of 15-03-2015

Now the `Array` should be sorted so that the values of 'ReceivedAt' will be sorted from earliest date, to the last date.

Hope this makes sense, but it's a bit difficult to explain. Thanks!

EDIT >>>>>

This is the `println(messageArray)` output:

```
[(
    {
    ConversationId = "94cc96b5-d063-41a0-ae03-6d1a868836fb";
    Data = "Hello World";
    Id = "eeb5ac08-209f-4ef0-894a-72e77f01b80b";
    NeedsPush = 0;
    ReceivedAt = "/Date(1439920899537)/";
    SendAt = "/Date(1436620515000)/";
    Status = 0;
    },
    {
    ConversationId = "94cc96b5-d063-41a0-ae03-6d1a868836fb";
    Data = "Hello World";
    Id = "86b8766d-e4b2-4ef6-9112-ba9193048d9d";
    NeedsPush = 0;
    ReceivedAt = "/Date(1439921562909)/";
    SendAt = "/Date(1436620515000)/";
    Status = 0;
    }
)]
```

And the received date is converted to a string with the following method (I do think however this is not important, as it is a time interval, and therefore OK to sort):

```
func getTimeStampFromAPIValue(dateTimeReceived: String) -> String {
    let newStartIndex = advance(dateTimeReceived.startIndex, 6)
    let newEndIndex = advance(dateTimeReceived.endIndex, -2)

    let substring = dateTimeReceived.substringWithRange(newStartIndex..<newEndIndex) // ell
    let receivedAtValueInInteger = (substring as NSString).doubleValue
    let receivedAtValueInDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970:receivedAtValueInInteger/1000)

    //format date
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yy hh:mm"
    var dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(receivedAtValueInDate)

    return dateString
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the values of `ReceivedAt` are timestamps as strings you could apply the following algorithm:

```
var sortedArray = messageArray.sorted { (dict1, dict2) in

    // Get the ReceivedAt value as strings
    if let date1String = dict1["ReceivedAt"] as? String,
       let date2String = dict2["ReceivedAt"] as? String {

        // Compare the date strings to find the earlier of the two
        return date1String.compare(date2String) == .OrderedAscending
    }

    // Couldn't parse the date, make an assumption about the order
    return true
}
```

Comment: Have tried 1st approach and created a func (the date was a string), but it looks as if the code never goes inside the `var sortedArray = messageArray.sorted { (dict1, dict2) in` part. Am I missing something here? Thanks!

Comment: The only reason for this would be that `messageArray` is empty.

Comment: @Hugo your dates are as Strings or NSdate instances?

Comment: @AndreiLuca he said in the first comment that it's a string.

Comment: @SteveWilford Have added the output of println() of the array values, and the way I convert this to a string in my original post as and edit

Comment: See my updated answer, the new information makes the process a bit easier, you dont actually need to convert the `ReceivedAt` value to a date in order to sort it. Since it is based on a timestamp you can use the built-in string comparison function.

Comment: @stevewilford Thanks for the update, but sorry, but it still does not go into this line: `var sortedArray = messageArray.sorted { (dict1, dict2) in` even after checking the Array is filled (see Edit for contents of the Array) What am I missing.

Comment: Actually the `sorted` function wouldn't be called if the array only contains a single item. I have just reviewed the output in your question and it looks like the array contains a single tuple which contains two dictionaries. Can you confirm?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. That was the hard part to explain in my initial question. ;)

Comment: I'm sorry but that is a terrible structure and makes it unnecessarily difficult to work with. Is there any way you can just add the dictionaries to the array directly without wrapping them in a tuple? It seems that the array will only ever contain a single value (a tuple with a variable number of dictionaries).

Comment: You are right I guess, I will clean up my code! This is coming from earlier experiments with the Dictionary and Array's. After that I will use the above code to sort the stuff, then it should work. Thanks a million for helping me figuring this out!

Comment: No problem. Apologies if I sounded a bit harsh but a good data structure will make your coding life easier :)

Comment: After finally figuring out the correct way to deal with Array and Dictionary and nest them the stuff is finally working. Including the sort you proposed! Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, change `OrderedAscending` with `OrderedDescending` if need in inverse order

```
messageArray.sortInPlace {
    ($0["ReceivedAt"] as! NSDate).compare($1["ReceivedAt"] as! NSDate) == .OrderedAscending
}
```

Comment: I'm not convinced this will work at all. The `>` operator can't be applied to `NSDate` operands. Applying it to strings won't work either as "15-08-2015" would end up before "21-03-2015" even though "21-03-2015" is earlier.

Comment: how about now as NSDate :)

Comment: Yes, and I actually prefer the compare method to my approach... However this still won't work as the dates in the OP are actually stored as strings.